# Cant use method parameters to succesfully execute some tweenlite code

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

Hi I got a weird problem, because I am trying to move a MovieClip object with the folowing code:

```
TweenLite.from(Dus, 1, { y:- Dus.height ,ease:Cubic.easeOut,alpha:0, onComplete:moveToTopLeftCorner2(Dus)});

    public function moveToTopLeftCorner2(mc:MovieClip):void{
        trace(mc);
         TweenLite.to(mc, .8, {x: 30, y: 40, onComplete:setObjectSmaller2});
        }
```

Unfortunately the code above me doesn't let the MovieClip object move to the top-left corner. But I have checked it with "trace(mc);" to see if there is a MovieClip object in the variable mc. So I have then checked the output of "trace(mc);" and it was:

```
[object MovieClip]
```

However this piece of code actually lets the MovieClip object move to the top-left corner.

```
TweenLite.from(Dus, 1, { y:- Dus.height ,ease:Cubic.easeOut,alpha:0, onComplete:moveToTopLeftCorner});

public function moveToTopLeftCorner():void{

         TweenLite.to(Dus, .8, {x: 30, y: 40, onComplete:setObjectSmaller2});

        }
```

My question is: why doesn't the moveToTopLeftCorner2(mc:MovieClip) method move a MovieClip object to the top-left corner? While the moveToTopLeftCorner() method does move a MovieClip object to the top-left corner. I have also recorded myself to show you guys the output and the display of the MovieClip object. Here is the link to the video:

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jgFNxd99MI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `onComplete:moveToTopLeftCorner2(Dus)` you are setting the `onComplete` value to the result of `moveToTopLeftCorner2(Dus)` which is `void`.

Instead, you need to just set it as a reference to the actual function: `onComplete:moveToTopLeftCorner2`.

You can provide arguments to this function using the special `onCompleteParams` option and sending it an array of arguments: `onCompleteParams: [Dus]`.

---

So all in all:

```
TweenLite.from(Dus, 1, 
              { y:- Dus.height ,ease:Cubic.easeOut,alpha:0,
               onComplete:moveToTopLeftCorner2, onCompleteParams: [Dus]});

public function moveToTopLeftCorner2(mc:MovieClip):void {
   trace(mc);
   TweenLite.to(mc, .8, {x: 30, y: 40, onComplete:setObjectSmaller2});
}
```

---

However, this was is slightly annoying, because you have to specify `Dus` twice in your code. Instead, you can use the special `"{self}"` argument.

```
TweenLite.from(Dus, 1, 
       { y:- Dus.height, ease:Cubic.easeOut,alpha:0,
         onComplete:moveToTopLeftCorner2, onCompleteParams: ["{self}"]});

public function moveToTopLeftCorner2(tween:TweenLite):void {
   var mc = tween.target;
   TweenLite.to(mc, .8, {x: 30, y: 40, onComplete:setObjectSmaller2});
}
```

Now your `onComplete` function gets back an instance of the tween you created and you can use it to access the object that was tweened.

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I still get a error. For your first piece of code I get the folowing error: 
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Model::mediumRectangle/moveToTopLeftCorner2(). Expected 1, got 0.

For the second piece of code I also get the same error. I also had checked this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-debug-an-as3-error-1063--active-9541. But the solution was the same which you had given to me. Is there maybe some other solution?

Comment: @superkytoz Whoops! I had been using `onCompleteArgs` instead of `onCompleteParams` in my examples. Fixed and try now!

Comment: Sweet your first piece of code works! But for the second one I still get a error hehe. Here is the error if you want it to know:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "{self}" to com.greensock.TweenLite.

If you know the solution, please let me know. Because I am still curious hehe.

Comment: @superkytoz Hmm, good question. If you look at [the docs](http://greensock.com/asdocs/) you can see where it's talking about `onCompleteParams` you can see it talking about how `"{self}"` is a special value you can supply to reference the Tween. Maybe you have an older version that doesn't support that feature? Hard to say unfortunately what's causing the error

Comment: Ye it was because I had an older version of the library. Now I have got the latest version of Tweenlite, and it works now :).